# How to replace "<space>" with "\\<space>" in groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

Tried with

```
def resultString="Hello word result Hello: 0 Word: 0 void: 0"
def resultString1=resultString.replaceAll(' ', '\\\\ ')
println resultString1
```

Expected Result:

```
Hello\\ word\\ result\\ Hello:\\ 0\\ Word:\\ 0\\ void:\\ 0
```

Actual Getting:

```
Hello\ word\ result\ Hello:\ 0\ Word:\ 0\ void:\ 0
```

Any input will be very useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def resultString="Hello word result Hello: 0 Word: 0 void: 0" println(resultString.replaceAll("\\s","\\\\\\\\"))`

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-
`replaceAll` uses Regex Matching, which changes the behaviour of the escaping

use `replace` instead:

```
def resultString="Hello word result Hello: 0 Word: 0 void: 0"
def resultString1=resultString.replace(' ','\\\\')
println resultString1
```

output:

```
Hello\\word\\result\\Hello:\\0\\Word:\\0\\void:\\0
```